# Which version of s3cmd does support IAM Roles?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd, amazon-iam

I am using latest version of s3cmd 1.5.2. As per this [post](http://t1983.file-systems-s3-s3tools.file-systemstalk.info/s3cmd-1-5-0-alpha2-iam-roles-supportincluded-t1983.html), 1.5.0-alpha2 supports IAM Roles, so I am assuming this must be supported in 1.5.2 as well. I added "security_token" in s3cfg file as mentioned in this [post](https://www.geekpete.com/blog/use-s3cmd-with-aws-iam-roles/). But I am still getting error "ERROR: S3 error: The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records." Am I doing something wrong or this version doesn't support IAM Roles?

Comment: why not use aws-cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the answer myself. After diving into the s3cmd code, found out that instead of adding "**security_token**" as mentioned in the [post](https://www.geekpete.com/blog/use-s3cmd-with-aws-iam-roles/) and other sources, we need to add "**access_token**" in the s3cfg file. If you are using s3cmd on a cluster associated with a role then there is no need to pass any s3cfg file as well. All releases from **1.5.0-alpha2 and above** support IAM Roles.

Answer (score 1):

These days, it is recommended to use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

As with any software that uses the AWS SDK, the AWS CLI will automatically use role-based credentials if the Amazon EC2 instance is launched with a role. Credentials can also be specified via environment variables or a configuration file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion,

Comment: The AWS CLI S3 submodule is extremely feature-limited (as of 2016-05-17) compared to S3 (no way to disable multi-part uploads, no ability to silence or increase verbosity of output, etc).

Comment: @BrandonGalbraith Take a look at `aws s3api` -- it has all of the API calls. use `aws s3` for Linux-like commands.

Comment: Thanks @JohnRotenstein! I was unaware of `aws s3api`.